# Deleting rows from the main table using a column of Temp table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor, sql-delete

I Have to delete stackID's which are there in ##BeDel from Main table by using @flow.

```
#BeDel

StackID
45
56
48
56
49


DECLARE @flow int
@flow=(SELECT FLOWID FROM MainTable WHERE FLOWNAME='AAA')

MainTable

StackID   VALUE  FLOWID   FLOWNAME   
67         34     1          AAA
45         56     1          AAA
56         22     1          AAA
34         56     1          ZZZ
```

I have done using cursors but i dont want to use cursors for the perfomance reason.

My cursor Code is

```
DECLARE Rotation CURSOR 
FOR 
                  SELECT StackID FROM #BeDel
                   DECLARE  StackID INT

                   OPEN Rotation
                   FETCH NEXT FROM Rotation INTO @StackID
                   While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                   BEGIN
                   DELETE MainTable
                   WHERE StackID=@StackID AND FLOWID=@@flow

                   FETCH NEXT FROM Rotation INTO @StackID 

                   END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete MainTable
from MainTable as m
where
    exists (select * from #BeDel as b where b.StackID = m.StackID) and
    m.FLOWNAME = 'AAA'
```